# Omit first parameter in for loop

Tags: java, php, c++, for-loop

In PHP, Java, C++ (and many other languages), for loops are used like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
```

If I already initialized `i`, how can I omit the initialization statement?

Comment: Just leave it out.. `;` is a valid statement in java and co.

Comment: Or write it as `while( i++ < 10 )`

Comment: They aren't parameters. The first and third are statements; the second is a condition. The null statement is legal in Java.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Java, C++ and PHP it is completely valid to omit the initialization portion of the `for` loop

```
int i = 0;
...
for(; i < 10; i++);
```

This is true of most languages which have a `for` loop structure

Comment: @Michael thanks for the clarification. Don't use PHP enough to say for certain off hand and was looking up the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(; i < 10; i++) {
    ...
}
```

You can leave out any of the items in the for loop if they are not needed. You could also put in multiple things to do, or multiple conditions to check such as:

```
int j = 40;
for(int i = 0; i < 10 || j > 30; i++, j--) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for C++, PHP you could just do this. Not sure of the syntax for other languages.  You could do the same with a while statement if you want to declare outside the loop.

```
for(;i<10;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that, if you have an array to iterate and don't want to use the standard "for", you can always use "foreach ($array as $var)" (on PHP) or the other "for ( X : )" on Java :)